# How to find the number of columns in a 2d std::array

Tags: c++, arrays, multidimensional-array

I have this function, which checks if all rows are equal in a 2d std::string array:

```
template <int sizeElements, int sizeArrays>
bool CheckEquality2dArray(const array<array<string, sizeElements>, sizeArrays> &my2dArray)
{
    if (equal(my2dArray.begin() + 1, my2dArray.end(), my2dArray.begin()))
    {
        return true;
    }
    else
    {
        return false;
    }
}
```

I am using templates, so that I can pass the number of columns (elements per row/array) and the number of rows (std::arrays). I can then use the function on any 2d std::array.

My question is: How do i pass the number of elements per row?

Example on a 2d std::array "myFirst2dArray":

```
if (checkArray.CheckEquality2dArray</*INSERT SOMETHING HERE*/, (int)myFirst2dArray.size()>(myFirst2dArray) == true)
{
    //Do something      
}
```

I can't do something like `(int)myFirst2dArray[0].size()`. I know i can solve this problem by using vectors, but is there a way with arrays?

Comment: By the way, `if (condition) return true; else return false;` is equivalent to `return condition;`.

Comment: @Melebius My pet hate. I can still remember the blank looks on some of my fellow students faces when the professor explained this.

Comment: I didn't know you could do that xD

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've changed the template arguments to:

```
template <size_t sizeElements, size_t sizeArrays>
```

I then deleted the template parameters when i used the function (thanks to molbdnilo) and everything is working now :)

Answer (score 0):

Those are your template parameters; you don't pass them since they are part of the type.
You only need to pass the array to the function, since the compiler already knows the dimensions.
Like this:

```
CheckEquality2dArray(myFirst2dArray);
```